# How to delete control file in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle

I am practicing the rman backup in oracle 11g.and how to dalete the control file. Please help.

rm -rf \oracle\app\oracle\oradata\xe\control.dbf

it did not work at hosting server.

Comment: why you want to delete the control files?

Comment: I want to try the Backup with RMAN so i want to delete the control file.

Comment: ,you can take backup of RMAN without delete the control files?

Comment: Could you update the O.S environment? If you are getting any Backup through RMAN Backup then please update that for better clarification.

Comment: O.S environment already upadated

Comment: Oracle is RDBMS database. I mean O.S environment like (Windows , Linux, Sun Solaris, etc).

Comment: Error showing SP2-0734 unknown command beggining

Comment: Where you are getting the error  'SP2-0734' unknown command beginning.

Comment: in SQL> application

Comment: but i also try it in OS level

Comment: How you are taking the RMAN Backup?

Comment: in RMAN> backup incrementel level 1/o databse plus asrchivelog format '--'

Comment: what is your 'log_mode'? I mean type in SQL promt like 'select  log_mode from v$database;. It's Archivelog mode or nonarchive log mode.

Comment: Archivelog mode

Comment: First thing, I find it weird your control file extension be .dbf (it normally is ctl). Second: to effectively delete a control file, stop your instance. Delete the file, open the database in no mount state. Perform an alter system to change the parameter Control_Files, and remove the location of the deleted control file. Open the database.

Answer (score 1):

`RMAN` is a oracle utility to backup, restore & recovery of database.

The following Steps will be demonstrated the configuration of oracle RMAN backup (for first time configuration)

Lets assume the database is in NOARCHIVELOG mode, by default the database is in NOARCHIVELOG mode, we need to change it to ARCHIVELOG mode for RMAN backup configuration.
We can configure RMAN backup with catalog/repository database as well as control file. It is strongly recommended & very good practice to configure RMAN backup with catalog/repository database.

Note: Be sure you have installed oracle 11g successfully in your environment.
I had asked to you about O.S environment. I didn't get any clue from you. So as a example i am writing the all RMAN backup steps in Windows O.S environment.

First open the command prompt and try to connect sql server as per your environment credential. for example

**Step # 1:** Connect to Target database(Target DB: The database on which Backup & Recovery to be performed) as sysdba.

```
C:\> set Oracle_sid=orcl
c:\> sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed Jul 26 10:17:22 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.
```

[image]

**Step # 2:** Ensure the database has been configured with ARCHIVELOG mode or not?

SQL> select log_mode from v$database;

### LOG_MODE

NOARCHIVELOG
Database is in NOARCHIVELOG mode.

[image]

**Step # 3:** If the database has been configured with ARCHIVELOG mode then skip the Step number 3 to 6, If not then Shutdown the database.

```
SQL> shutdown immediate;
Database closed.
Database dismounted.
ORACLE instance shut down.
```

**Step # 4:** Startup the database in mount state.

```
SQL> startup mount;
ORACLE instance started.
Total System Global Area 308981760 bytes
Fixed Size 2212896 bytes
Variable Size 163580896 bytes
Database Buffers 138412032 bytes
Redo Buffers 4775936 bytes
Database mounted.
```

**Step # 5:** Configure database in ARCHIVELOG mode.

```
SQL> alter database archivelog;
Database altered.
```

**Step # 6:** Alter database to open state.

```
SQL> alter database open;
Database altered.

SQL> select open_mode from v$database;
OPEN_MODE
--------------------
READ WRITE
```

**Step # 7:** Ensure ARCHIVELOG destination.

```
SQL> archive log list;
Database log mode              Archive Mode
Automatic archival             Enabled
Archive destination            USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST
Oldest online log sequence     330
Next log sequence to archive   332
Current log sequence           332
```

[image]

**Step # 8:** Ensure the flash/fast recovery area location.

```
SQL> show parameter db_recovery_file_dest;

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
db_recovery_file_dest                string      C:\app\xyz\flash_recove
                                                 ry_area
db_recovery_file_dest_size           big integer 3852M
```

Note : Here i did 'xyz' in C:\app\xxx\flash_recovery_area. due to security reason.
[image]

**Step # 9:** Connect to RMAN prompt with target database.

```
C:\>rman target/

Recovery Manager: Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Sun Jul 30 12:32:57 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

connected to target database: ORCL (DBID=1464491423)
```

[image]

**Step # 10 :** To show the all configuration of your RMAN through this command.

```
RMAN> show all;

using target database control file instead of recovery catalog
RMAN configuration parameters for database with db_unique_name ORCL are:
CONFIGURE RETENTION POLICY TO RECOVERY WINDOW OF 7 DAYS;
CONFIGURE BACKUP OPTIMIZATION OFF; # default
CONFIGURE DEFAULT DEVICE TYPE TO DISK; # default
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP OFF; # default
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO '%F'; # default
CONFIGURE DEVICE TYPE DISK PARALLELISM 1 BACKUP TYPE TO BACKUPSET; # default
CONFIGURE DATAFILE BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
CONFIGURE CHANNEL DEVICE TYPE DISK FORMAT   '/backup/rman/full_%u_%s_%p';
CONFIGURE MAXSETSIZE TO UNLIMITED; # default
CONFIGURE ENCRYPTION FOR DATABASE OFF; # default
CONFIGURE ENCRYPTION ALGORITHM 'AES128'; # default
CONFIGURE COMPRESSION ALGORITHM 'BASIC' AS OF RELEASE 'DEFAULT' OPTIMIZE FOR LOAD TRUE ; # default
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG DELETION POLICY TO NONE; # default
CONFIGURE SNAPSHOT CONTROLFILE NAME TO 'C:\APP\xyz\PRODUCT\11.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\SNCFORCL.ORA'; # default
```

[image]

Note : -  As per this statement  'CONFIGURE CHANNEL DEVICE TYPE DISK FORMAT   '/backup/rman/full_%u_%s_%p';' I hope you have created the folder '/backup/rman' in your c: drive.
[image]
Typically we’ll use “BACKUP AS BACKUPSET” to backup a database. So, to take a full backup of the database without the archive logs, do the following.

```
RMAN> BACKUP AS BACKUPSET DATABASE

RMAN> backup as backupset database;

Starting backup at 30-JUL-17
allocated channel: ORA_DISK_1
channel ORA_DISK_1: SID=75 device type=DISK
channel ORA_DISK_1: starting full datafile backup set
channel ORA_DISK_1: specifying datafile(s) in backup set
input datafile file number=00002 name=C:\APP\xyz\ORADATA\ORCL\SYSAUX01.DBF
input datafile file number=00001 name=C:\APP\xyz\ORADATA\ORCL\SYSTEM01.DBF
input datafile file number=00003 name=C:\APP\xyz\ORADATA\ORCL\UNDOTBS01.DBF
input datafile file number=00005 name=C:\APP\xyz\ORADATA\ORCL\EXAMPLE01.DBF
input datafile file number=00004 name=C:\APP\xyz\ORADATA\ORCL\USERS01.DBF
channel ORA_DISK_1: starting piece 1 at 30-JUL-17
channel ORA_DISK_1: finished piece 1 at 30-JUL-17
piece handle=C:\BACKUP\RMAN\FULL_11SAL7BV_33_1 tag=TAG20170730T125212 comment=NONE
channel ORA_DISK_1: backup set complete, elapsed time: 00:02:16
channel ORA_DISK_1: starting full datafile backup set
channel ORA_DISK_1: specifying datafile(s) in backup set
including current control file in backup set
including current SPFILE in backup set
channel ORA_DISK_1: starting piece 1 at 30-JUL-17
channel ORA_DISK_1: finished piece 1 at 30-JUL-17
piece handle=C:\BACKUP\RMAN\FULL_12SAL7G7_34_1 tag=TAG20170730T125212 comment=NONE
channel ORA_DISK_1: backup set complete, elapsed time: 00:00:02
Finished backup at 30-JUL-17
```

[image]

[image]
For further your ref [Here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/08/oracle-rman-backup/) and [Here](https://dbatricksworld.com/how-to-configure-oracle-rman-backup-for-the-first-time/)

Comment: delete command to control file in windows OS Oracle 11g. And then restore command to in oracle 11g.

Comment: I want command for delete or remove one or more control file or data filein oracle 11g in windows OS.

Comment: @surendra -     Aside from the question of "why", your opening statement "it did not work at hosting server." is devoid of actionable information. What error was returned? You showed a *nix "rm" command, but now you are asking hwo to remove files in Windows.  The Windows command for deleting a file is 'del <filename>'

Comment: I USE DEL command for delete the control file .but it throw an error it is being used by another process.

Comment: anyone can suggest